# Upgrade MSF ssh to meterpreter on a host behind a forwarded host

Tags: ssh, metasploit, meterpreter, msfvenom

I'm training on a test network. I managed to snatch some ssh credentials and spawn a shell with msfconsole. Turns out a connection via ssh to `192.168.0.3:2222` forwards me to `192.168.0.4:22`. So I have the shell on `192.168.0.4`.

Now I want to upgrade the ssh session to a meterpreter. I saw that meterpreter is able to bind to the remote ssh shell as `lhost` but I don't receive the meterpreter.

I could run a normal ssh shell with the -R option and inject some msfvenom, but I wanted to test whether it's possible to do this only with msfconsole.

The setup:

```
192.168.0.2 <---> 192.168.0.3 <---> 192.168.0.4
```

Problem: outgoing connections from `192.168.0.4` get blocked by `192.168.0.3` and can not reach the attacker on `192.168.0.2` and the attacker can only connect to `192.168.0.4` via the forwarded port.

my options:

```
(post/multi/manage/shell_to_meterpreter)
HANDLER     true
LHOST       192.168.0.4
LPORT       4433
SESSION     1
```